# trying python tkinter creating widgets with classes (frame)

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, frame

I am trying to create custom widgets with classes. I have one class, called `CustomWidgets` inside it, I have method for creating `Frame` object, then configure its `side` key with `config` method, but it gives an error.

code;

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class CustomWidgets():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.frm_upp=self.frm()
        self.frm_upp.config(side='top')

    def frm(self):
        self.frm_0=LabelFrame(master=self.root)
        self.frm_0.pack(expand='YES')
```

error;

```
    self.frm_upp=self.frm().config(side='top')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

I guess, when I assign `self.frm_upp` variable to method `self.frm()` it does not assign and thus gives Nonetype object.

Comment: `self.frm()` is a function which returns `None`.  So why do you expect `self.frm().config(...)` work like what you want? Also `side` is not a valid option of a tkinter widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `self.frm` returns `None` since you don't explicitly set a return value. If you want to be able to use the return value of the function, you must use the `return` statement.

However, you have another problem in that `side` isn't an attribute of a frame widget. It's an attribute of the `pack` command, so you'll need to modify the line that calls `config` to instead call `pack_configure`:

```
class CustomWidgets():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.frm_upp=self.frm()
        self.frm_upp.pack_configure(side='top')

    def frm(self):
        self.frm_0=LabelFrame(master=self.root)
        self.frm_0.pack(expand='YES')
        return self.frm_0
```